# javascript checking time and insert data using setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

hi guys need help on this one i have a javascript code that identify and display the time on pc(it is base on pc time). i have this condition when it is true should insert the data to database. i use setinterval so when the condition is true it will go to that page or php code(fetch.php code is below). i post all the code in below hopping of help guys. WELL THE PROBLEM IS THAT THE IT IS NOT INSERTING DATA INTO DATABASE.

here is the index.php

```js
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
     
     
     if(h == '6' && m == '00')
     {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
        $('#auto').load('fetch.php')
        },1000);
      });
    }
     
     
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
        return i;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="startTime()">
    
    <div id="txt"></div>
    
    <div id="auto"></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the fetch.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl(available)
VALUES ('200')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: did you mean `index.js` ?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: it is a index.php. just most of the code is javascript

Comment: @AlexHowansky edited already]

Comment: So do some troubleshooting. Is the remote page even getting requested? What does it return?

Comment: does not returning anything.

Comment: but i tried $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
    $('#auto').load('fetch.php')
    },1000);
  });

Comment: that function into this one alert("some text"); and work perfectly. it notify me a "some thing".

Comment: Tip: Instead of `$(document).ready(function { ... })` you can do `$(function { ... })` instead.